# MongoDB very slow result with $lookup

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using PHP to interact with MongoDB, recently I used `$lookup` on 5 collection and my query starts taking around 20-25 seconds to get the result. All my collections have testing data which is not more than 30-40 entries. I also used profiling but I am getting message: "Query Not Recording (too Large)"

I am sharing code from my PHP file. I have also tried creating index on field which are creating joins between collection but got same result. Please let me the the best way to create collection structure and to retrieve data from MongoDB.

Thanks in advance.

```
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'col_main');
    $condition = array();
    $condition[] = array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                "from" => "col_a",
                "localField" => "a",
                "foreignField" => "_id",
                "as" => "col_a"
            )
        );
    $condition[] = array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                "from" => "col_b",
                "localField" => "b",
                "foreignField" => "_id",
                "as" => "col_b"
            )
        );

    $condition[] = array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                "from" => "col_c",
                "localField" => "c",
                "foreignField" => "_id",
                "as" => "col_c"
            )
        );

    $condition[] = array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                "from" => "col_e",
                "localField" => "e",
                "foreignField" => "_id",
                "as" => "col_e"
            )
        );

    $condition[] = array(
            '$lookup' => array(
                "from" => "col_f",
                "localField" => "f",
                "foreignField" => "_id",
                "as" => "col_f"
            )
        );      

    $condition[]  = array(
            '$project' => $projection
        );

    $condition[] = array ( 
                    '$unwind' => '$col_a'

                );

    $condition[] = array (
                    '$unwind' => '$col_a.translation'

                );      

    $condition[] = array ( 
                    '$unwind' => '$col_b'

                );

    $condition[] = array (
                    '$unwind' => '$col_b.translation'

                );

    $condition[] = array ( 
                    '$unwind' => '$col_c'

                );

    $condition[] = array (
                    '$unwind' => '$col_c.translation'

                );

    $condition[] = array ( 
                    '$unwind' => '$col_e'

                );

    $condition[] = array (
                    '$unwind' => '$col_e.staff_name'

                );

    $condition[] = array (
                    '$unwind' => '$col_e.staff_surname'

                );          

    $condition[] = array ( 
                    '$unwind' => '$col_f'

                );

    $condition[] = array (
                    '$unwind' => '$col_f.translation'

                );      


    //Some More conditions

        $condition[] = array(
                    '$match' => array( 'col_b.translation.language' => $val )
                );
            $condition[] = array(
                    '$match' => array( 'col_a.translation.language' => $val )
                );
            $condition[] = array(
                    '$match' => array( 'col_c.translation.language' => $val )
                );  

            $condition[] = array(
                    '$match' => array( 'col_f.translation.language' => $val )
                );              


    return  $collection->aggregate($condition);
```

Comment: checkmemory usage during query execution

Comment: Nothing unusual with memory usage

Comment: Don't abuse the use of `$lookup` It will cause a drop of performance in your application.

Comment: That the issue I am facing but what is the best way to get data in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are multiplying object using many unwind operations this could produce a huge set of data, every `$unwind` muliplayes documnet set, so there could be a huge memory consumption and even swapping.

if we have 3 arrays 3 elements each, then we will perform unwind on a, b, c
we will get:

- 3 documents after first step,
- 9 documents after 2nd step
- 27 documents after last step..

Comment: Thanks for you explanation.

Initially we created nested documents but due to [THIS](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) issue we switched to separated collection. So what you suggest to retrieve data from structure like this. Should I fetch data one by one from collection using PHP using loop?

Comment: @Gurveer - tbh it depends of amount of retrieved data. If we are talking ~1k that could be legit, but more documents will introduce latency

Comment: There will more than 50k records. So what Should I do now? $lookup is slow map-reduce may slow in future when I have more data so what options do I left with? :(

Comment: @gurveer there is always a solution,  we are learning by doing so probably there some options to go with.  As joining is not recommended in mongo and deep nesting either,  so I am wondering how we can flatten structure to overcome this limitations,  but this requires more business knowledge....